# double qoutes in variables causing javascript error

Tags: php, javascript

In my below code when the `$artist` or `$title` variables contain " it causes the JavaScript command to break.

Is there another way I can encode these other than addslashes() to fix this?

```
$artist = addslashes($row['artist']);
    $title = addslashes($row['title']);

    echo '<div class="play" style="display: inline"><a href="javascript:playSong'."('$artist','$title','$row[file]','$row[id]')".'">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can consider url encoding for variables, like

```
$artist = rawurlencode($row['artist']);
$title = rawurlencode($row['title']);

echo "..... playSong(unescape('$artist'), unescape('$title')... ";
```

or move decoding into playSong function.

// edit: this is how you get your quotes right

```
echo "<div class='play' style='display: inline'><a href=\"javascript:playSong(unescape('$artist'),unescape('$title'),'$row[file]','$row[id]')\">....";
```

Comment: The problem is that if there is " in the echo ''; it breaks the JavaScript command not it displaying wrong. So I need to encapsulate the variables correctly I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `urlencode()`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

`echo '<div class="play" style="display: inline"> 
<a href="javascript:playSong('$artist','$title','$row[file]','$row[id]')" >'`

Comment: i formatted your code, because the tags were stripped out. `echo ' '` made me lol